# Issue to escape curly brace in the url of an Unirest.get

Tags: java, rest, unirest

I'm trying to retrieve the result of this rest endpoint:

[http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/Geometry/GeometryServer/distance?sr=4326&geometry1={"geometryType":"esriGeometryPoint","geometry":{"x":43.5664375,"y":1.4675999}}&geometry2={"geometryType":"esriGeometryPoint","geometry":{"x":49.120329,"y":6.164786}}&geodesic=true&f=pjson](http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/Geometry/GeometryServer/distance?sr=4326&geometry1=%7B%22geometryType%22:%22esriGeometryPoint%22,%22geometry%22:%7B%22x%22:43.5664375,%22y%22:1.4675999%7D%7D&geometry2=%7B%22geometryType%22:%22esriGeometryPoint%22,%22geometry%22:%7B%22x%22:49.120329,%22y%22:6.164786%7D%7D&geodesic=true&f=pjson)

Here is how I am doing:

```
 String geometry1 = "geometry1={\"geometryType\":\"esriGeometryPoint\",\"geometry\":{\"x\":43.5664375,\"y\":1.4675999}}";
 String geometry2 = "geometry2={\"geometryType\":\"esriGeometryPoint\",\"geometry\":{\"x\":49.120329,\"y\":6.164786}}";

 try {
        response5 = Unirest.get("http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/Geometry/GeometryServer/distance?sr=4326&{geometry1}&{geometry2}&geodesic=true&f=pjson")
                .routeParam("geometry1", geometry1)
                .routeParam("geometry2", geometry2)
                .asJson();
    } catch (UnirestException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I get this error where the illegal character is the first curly brace of my url: `geomtry1={`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 122
```

How can I escape the curly braces ? I tried `URLEncoder.encode`. That escape the curcly braces but that seem to doesn't format the url correctly because i get the error : `geometry1' must be specified","'geometry2' must be specified`.

Comment: One idea would be to get the elements as String instead of JSON and then convert. It might be a bit slower though.

Comment: The problem is not on the parse of body but in the unirest.get where the url string passed contain curly braces and for java a curly braces in a string seems to be an Illegal character

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise that. Try replacing `{` with `%7B` and `}` with `%7D` in the URL. May not be different than `URLEncoder.encode`, but worth trying.